# Perdi contraseña de keystore en app ya subida

Tags: java, android, android-studio

despues de mucho investigar tengo que consultarlo... Tengo una app subida al play store antigua la cual actualmente intente subir una actualizacion y no logro recordar el password...

Tengo el archivo .jks y tengo el alias. Con el programa KeyStoreExplorer abro la key (cuando me pide la contraseña la ingreso y me da como correcta, mi duda es si esta contraseña que ingreso es la "key store password" o la "key password")

Al leer el archivo executionHistory.bin me figura otra keyalias que no es la misma que la que me muestra el archivo cuando lo abro con el keyStoreExplorer... y las passwordStore que me muestra estan encriptadas y no se como desencriptarlas.

Tambien intente con el keytool de java, ingreso el alias y la contraseña pero no me muestra la otra conseña y sigo con la duda de que contraseña es la que me falta.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: El valor por defecto tanto para `Keystore password` como para `Key password` es **`android`**. ¿Probaste a ponerlo cuando te pide las claves?

Comment: Si, tambien probe android pero nada...